# How to connect to external database in Spring Boot while maintaining connection with primary database

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

1 - So, I have been given a task to create a spring boot microservice that would connect to another microservice and delete table rows older than a certain date.

2 - I am fetching the external database credentials (URL, username, password, driver) via API endpoint and storing those credentials in my primary database.

3 - How do I now connect to an external database via the database creds I just stored and perform certain clean-up operations on tables.

4 - I have no interest in what's present in those tables. I just need to delete rows older than a specific date.

Comment: look here: https://blog.virtual7.de/dynamically-change-data-source-connection-details-at-runtime-in-spring-boot/

Comment: This blog was helpful. I tweaked it to my personal use and it now works! Thank you!